# How connect to Java program from Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, ftp, oracleforms

I want to copy a folder and everything that is included in it to a FTP by oracle.

I found out this work is a little bit hard with Oracle so I decided to write a program in Java and copy the file with a Java program but I dont have any idea about how I can make connection between an Oracle program and Java.

I want to submit the source folder and destination folder and my Java program easily do the copy for me and if the copy completed inform my oracle program(form).

would you please advise me should I use Java for FTP my files or it would be better I use Oracle forms technology for transferring my files?

I would so appreciate if you provide me a sample in java that I see how I can transfer my files to a ftp address.(if you have any sample in Oracle it would be even more better)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the PL/SQL Utility Library page

http://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/

Specifically the "Transfer files (FTP) using PL/SQL" section, there you will find the code you need to do this in PL/SQL (no Java required).